# How to get all lines after a line number

Tags: string, bash, match

I have a file like this:

```
string log 1 
string log 2
string match
string log 4
string match
string log 5
string log 6
```

I need to get all the lines after the last string match. How can I do it in bash?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, find the last string match:

```
line=$(grep -n 'string match' myFile | cut -d: -f1 | tail -1)
```

Then, print all lines up to that last string match:

```
sed -n "1,${line}p" myFile
```

If you need all lines after last match:

```
sed -n "$((line+1))"',$p' myFile
```

Answer (score 5):

I'm going to assume *in bash* allows for some external binary calls. With that in mind:

### All lines after the last match

```
tac infile | sed '/string match/,$d' | tac
```

#### Output

```
$ tac infile | sed '/string match/,$d' | tac
string log 5
string log 6
```

### All lines before the last match

```
tac infile | sed '1,/string match/d' | tac
```

#### Output

```
$ tac infile | sed '1,/string match/d' | tac
string log 1
string log 2
string match
string log 4
```

Comment: sorry, I need all lines after the last match

Comment: @Rikr np, now you have both ways =)

Answer (score 2):

### `awk` solution:

```
$ awk 'FNR==NR{if(/match/)x=NR; next}; FNR>x' input.txt{,}
string log 5
string log 6
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you:

```
sed 'H;/string match/,+1h;$!d;x' file
```

Answer (score 0):

I would personally use this sed method:

```
-bash-4.1$ cat file | sed -n 'H; /string match/h; ${g;p;}'
string match
string log 5
string log 6
-bash-4.1$ cat file | sed -n 'H; /string match/h; ${g;p;}' | grep -v 'string match'
string log 5
string log 6
```