# python return all lines after last regex match

Tags: python, regex, file, match

I bet it's an easy answer for fellow pythoners.
I'm a rookie and I've been searching for an answer for quite a while now (hours)...

**How to return all lines after last regex match (including and excluding match)?**
I'm playing with python 2.6

data:

```
string log 1 
string log 2
string match
string log 4
string match
string log 5
string log 6
```

expected case 1:

```
string match
string log 5
string log 6
```

expected case 2:

```
string log 5
string log 6
```

---

Same question for bash what posted here [How to get all lines after a line number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9274482/how-to-get-all-lines-after-a-line-number/18952877#18952877)

sed solution:

```
sed -n 'H; /string match/h; ${g;p;}'
sed -n 'H; /string match/h; ${g;p;}' | grep -v 'string match'
```

Comment: Would help to post the piece of code you're trying in python.

Comment: @Jerry - this is not a question about the code which doesn't work, but genuine use case. I've been looking for an appropriate function/method, but by the look of the first answer I can say there's no "one liner" solution

Comment: If 'string match' isn't in the text , what do you want as a result ? Btw , see my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking into a shorter piece of code, maybe that?

Case 1:

```
>>> import re
>>> input_data = open('path/file').read()
>>> result = re.search(r'.*(string match\s*.*)$', input_data, re.DOTALL)
>>> print(result.group(1))
string match
string log 5
string log 6
```

Case 2:

```
>>> import re
>>> input_data = open('path/file').read()
>>> result = re.search(r'.*string match\s*(.*)$', input_data, re.DOTALL)
>>> print(result.group(1))
string log 5
string log 6
```

Warning though, there'll be a *lot* of backtracking in that regex if the last 'string match' is way up in the file.

Comment: perfect - I knew python will have a "one liner". it's just well hidden for people like me.

Answer (score 0):

```
import sys

with open('/path/to/file', 'rb') as f:
    last_pos = pos = 0
    for line in f:
        pos += len(line)
        if 'string match' in line:
            last_pos = pos
    f.seek(last_pos)
    sys.stdout.writelines(f)
```

Used a loop to find last match position. Then used [file.seek](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.seek) to move file position.

Comment: thanks @falsetru - it does the trick for case #2 and can be easily modified for #1. I'm quite surprised python doesn't have such a functionality build in.

Answer (score 0):

```
t = '''string log 1 
string log 2
string match
string log 4
string match
string log 5
string log 6'''

me = t.rsplit('string match',1)[1].lstrip()

e = t[t.rfind('string match'):]

print '%s\n\n%r\n\n%r' % (t,me,e)
```

result

```
string log 1 
string log 2
string match
string log 4
string match
string log 5
string log 6

'string log 5\nstring log 6'

'string match\nstring log 5\nstring log 6'
```